# How to pass a channel to a function as a parameter?

Tags: go

I made two attempts to pass a channel to a function as a parameter, but they both fail (deadlock):

Attempt 1:

```
func done(signal *chan bool) {
    *signal <- true
}

func main() {
    signal := make(chan bool)
    done(&signal)
    <-signal
    fmt.Println("completed")
}
```

Attempt 2:

```
func done(signal chan bool) {
    signal <- true
}

func main() {
    signal := make(chan bool)
    done(signal)
    <-signal
    fmt.Println("completed")
}
```

Well I am out of ideas. What should be the proper way to pass the channel to the function?

Comment: In your case (and in nearly all cases) there is no reason to pass a pointer to a chan, map, or slice, or function value, since those are all reference types which internally contain a pointer. The exception would be if you want the callee to change the reference type header, rather than the data it refers to, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`done(&signal)` is called synchronously. Maybe what you wanted to do is to call it asynchronously?

to do so, put the keyword `go` in front of the function call

```
go done(&signal)
```

The main thread will block until the done function writes to the channel. And the done method will block on writing to the channel until the main thread reads the channel.

Answer (score 16):

A channel is unbuffered by default, so when you send on a channel, that send will block
until someone receives the value. This is clearly the case in your code here, at the point where you you're doing `signal <- true` , there's noone that can or ever will receive on the same channel.

You can create a goroutine that does the sending, that way execution in main() continues and there will be someone that's receiving the value:

```
go done(signal)
```

Or you can create a buffered channel, so sending on a channel doesn't block if there's room for the value in the channel:

```
 signal := make(chan bool, 1)
```